# Ruby on Rails: updated_at - set as 0 on creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When I create a new record on `query` table, I want `updated_at` (timestamp) to be '0000-00-00 00:00:00' - and not the current timestamp, as Ruby on Rails sets by default.

MySQL field:

```
`updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

However, Ruby on Rails generates this sql query:

```
INSERT INTO `queries` (`updated_at`) VALUES ('2011-01-04 17:40:15')
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rails sets `updated_at` to the current time because, well, thats when the record was most recently updated. It sees an update as a creation. If you want to check if something has ever been updated, check to see if its `updated_at` and `created_at` are the same.

Otherwise, you should be able to change the value inserted by forcing the attribute upon insertion.

`Post.new(@params.merge({:updated_at => DateTime::new})`

or, in a `before_create` method on your model, set `self.updated_at = DateTime::new`.

Comment: seems your answer is a bit off topic

Comment: This is the better solution; Swanand's solution would mean `updated_at` wouldn't work at all, which I assume isn't your intention, just that you want new records to have an `updated_at` = 0.

Comment: How is this off topic ... ? Maybe we interpreted the question differently?

Answer (score 1):

If you want `Rails` to skip recording the timestamps, you can utilize this API:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps = false
# This also works on individual models
Post.record_timestamps = false
```

Since `Rails` (`ActiveRecord` more appropriately) will not assign a value to this field, your DB will assign the default value to those fields.

Answer (score 0):

I recently discovered [this blog post on the subject](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2009/01/21/override-automatic-timestamp-in-activerecord-rails.html).

To summarize, he describes (with examples) methods for overriding ActiveRecord's default behavior with these timestamp columns.  He explains that ActiveRecord actually ignores provided updated_at information and always uses its own timestamps.

Ultimately, he monkey patches ActiveRecord to provide a new `update_without_timestamping` method that does the work of disabling and re-enabling timestamping **and** it's thread safe and only modifies the behavior of the model being worked on.

If you don't want to read the article, his final monkey patched code is as follows:

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base

    def update_record_without_timestamping
      class << self
        def record_timestamps; false; end
      end

      save!

      class << self
        remove_method :record_timestamps
      end
    end

  end
end
```