# Time vs Timestamp in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model for Event that I would like to have a user set date.

Is `:time` or `:timestamp` more appropriate? And is `date_select` the best form helper to use here? Or is there a nice gem for selecting from a calendar or something?

Comment: Does the event just have a date?  Is there a start time/end time?

Comment: It's more or less just a date on a calendar, but I would like to optionally be able to set it to a specific time. But no start/end. Just a time like 10/10/2012 at 5:00pm or (probably more commonly) just 10/10/2012. Thanks

Comment: Don't forget that Rails can [update timestamps for you automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596675/ruby-on-rails-updated-at-set-as-0-on-creation) -- can you use this functionality for your own uses?

Comment: @sarnold I don't think so? This would be more like a calendar where a user needs to say "The picnic occurs on June 5." I will be using the rails auto updated at and created at fields in the model as well.

Comment: Leave it to me to overlook the `from a calendar` in there. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend creating your migration with a field called `start` (or whatever seems appropriate to you) with a type of `:datetime` ([see here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#supported-types)).

From the view perspective, the 'vanilla' approach would be to use `datetime_select`.  Info [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-datetime_select).

You can probably find a lot prettier views with an unobtrusive pop-up calendar in JavaScript.  I don't have any particular recommendations in this area.